# Which module is the actual interface to FUSE from Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, freebsd, fuse

I'm just starting to learn FUSE and I'm going to use it with Python 3 under FreeBSD and MacOS. First of all, I'm a bit confused which module is the actual interface to FUSE from Python 3 side:

- https://github.com/libfuse/python-fuse which is Python 2.x/3.x bindings for libfuse 2.x
- https://github.com/libfuse/pyfuse3 which is a set of Python 3 bindings for libfuse 3 using asynchronous I/O. It enables you to easily write a full-featured Linux filesystem in Python.

So, it looks like, the actual version of FUSE library is 3 and it seems, I should use *pyfuse3*, but that remark about "Linux filesystem" makes me wonder if I should fallback to *python-fuse* to work happily under FreeBSD/MacOS.

Comment: To be clear, you are aware MacOS and OSX is not the same as FreeBSD, right?

Comment: @Rob, yes, I'm aware of it and I use both, no Linux though.

Answer (score 18):

Well, that's what I [found](https://github.com/libfuse/python-fuse/issues/6) at the moment. In short:

- [python-fuse](https://github.com/libfuse/python-fuse) is **in the official** *libfuse* organization but it was not maintained for some time. Now it seems there is a maintainer of the project, so I hope it will survive.
- [fusepy](https://github.com/terencehonles/fusepy) is **outside of official** *libfuse* organization. It is a single file and uses [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html).
- [refuse](https://github.com/pleiszenburg/refuse) is a fork of *fusepy*, and also uses [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html).
- Also, there is [pyfuse3](https://github.com/libfuse/pyfuse3) project which seems to be **official**, but no longer actively developed.
- Finally, there is another project [python-llfuse](https://github.com/python-llfuse/python-llfuse/) which is recommended by [Nikratio](https://github.com/libfuse/python-fuse/issues/6#issuecomment-303802252) one of the *libfuse* developers. [The *python-llfuse* project used to recommend pyfuse3, but not anymore](https://github.com/python-llfuse/python-llfuse/commit/c98ad683aa6669bba4e79f8a29b64182004a7609). It is also no longer actively developed.

So, as there is a **good-old-official** version that has a maintainer now, I tried to start with *python-fuse* on FreeBSD. Unfortunately it appeared to be [broken](https://github.com/libfuse/python-fuse/issues/14), so I wrote a [quick fix](https://github.com/libfuse/python-fuse/pull/15) to help building it on non-Linux OS.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Google search results keep giving me 1) at the top so I got diverted. I better correct course.

Comment: Trying to get pyfuse3 working on Mac was too tough for me. So tough I switched back to Java (the ultimate insult right?)

Comment: Besides the first bullet point, all other projects seem to be dead.

Comment: @TorstenBronger Even the first one looks almost dead. It looks like only one PR was merged in the last year but well it's still more alive than fusepy, for which I'm slowly trying to find a substitute that works with libfuse3. There also was [refuse](https://github.com/pleiszenburg/refuse), a fusepy fork but that also died out quickly it seems. The current state of python FUSE bindings seems demotivating.

Comment: Like it never happened